# ¿Como rellenar un array en Java Script y que en consola me muestre la selección del usuario?

Tags: javascript, array

Mediante prompt estoy pidiendole al usuario que seleccione 2 productos. Y luego necesito que me muestre en consola la seleccion de ambos productos. Pero solo me esta mostrando el ultimo seleccionado.Esto me muestra la consola. Yo necesito que me salgan los dos.

[image: Esto me muestra la consola]

// Creación de Objetos

```
class Producto {
constructor(titulo, precio, cantidad) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    };
}

const PRODUCTO = new Producto(material, calcularPrecio, cantidad);
```

// Array de Productos

```
const agregarAlCarrito = (producto) => {
carrito.push(producto);
};

const carrito = [];
const arrayProductos = [
{ id: 1, titulo: material, precio: precio, cantidad},
{ id: 2, titulo: material, precio: precio, cantidad},
];

agregarAlCarrito(arrayProductos[0, 1]);
console.log(carrito);

arrayProductos.forEach(productoEnCarrito => {
console.log(productoEnCarrito)
});
```

Comment: Cuando ejecutas `agregarAlCarrito(arrayProductos[0, 1]);` ¿estas intentando agregar los productos en la posición `0` y `1`?

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas pasar un array a tu función agregarAlCarrito(), entonces su implementación podría ser usando el operador spread (...):

```
const agregarAlCarrito = (productos) => {
  carrito.push(...productos);
};
```

O bien usando forEach():

```
const agregarAlCarrito = (productos) => {
   productos.forEach(p => carrito.push(p));
};
```

Y por último, pasamos la variable "arrayProductos" a la función:

```
agregarAlCarrito(arrayProductos);
```